# Create a slider for a constant used in a function

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to create a slider for the $k$ constant in the function $h(u)$ on the second line. The code outputs a graph that seems to be using too few points. The two pictures below use the same $k$-value, one with the "Manipulate"-function and the other without.

```
Manipulate[
     h[u_] = k*u^2;
     fun[u_, v_] = -v^2 + u^5 + u^4 + 4 u^3 + 4 u^2 + 3 u + 3 - h[u]*v ;

     P1 = {-1, y /. (Solve[fun[-1, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
     P1spec = { P1[[1]], -P1[[2]] - h[P1[[1]]]};
     P2 = {0, y /. (Solve[fun[0, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
     P2spec = { P2[[1]], -P2[[2]] - h[P2[[1]]]};
     P3 = {1, y /. (Solve[fun[1, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
     P3spec = { P3[[1]], -P3[[2]] - h[P3[[1]]]};


     ContourPlot[fun[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -15, 15}, 
      Epilog -> {PointSize[0.03],
        Red, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P1], 
        Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P1spec],
        Blue, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P2], 
        Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P2spec],
        Orange, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P3], 
        Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P3spec]}],
     {k, -2, 7}
]
```

[image: Output with manipulate]

[image: Output without manipulate]

Comment: This seems to work as is should in my copy of version 11.3 for macOS. The first picture looks like what I get when I move the slider and _do not release it_. Per default, Mathematica tries to increase responsiveness by computing in low quality during dynamic changes. But I don't know what went wrong in your case. Usually, releasing the mouse button leads to a high-definition render after a second or so.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, it doesn't change after releasing the mouse button. I'm using version 11.1.1 on Linux. Do you by any chance have an idea what the issue could be? Regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: you can try using the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in `ContourPlot` (the responsiveness tp slider movements will be slower)

Comment: @kglr, thank you, but unfortunately the exact same behavior.

Comment: Try to add the option `PlotPoints -> 50` to your plot statement. It may improve the quality of the plot. Play with the number of points.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, perfect! That solved it! Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the option `PlotPoints -> 50` to your plot statement as follows:

```
Manipulate[h[u_] = k*u^2;
 fun[u_, v_] = -v^2 + u^5 + u^4 + 4 u^3 + 4 u^2 + 3 u + 3 - h[u]*v;
 P1 = {-1, y /. (Solve[fun[-1, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
 P1spec = {P1[[1]], -P1[[2]] - h[P1[[1]]]};
 P2 = {0, y /. (Solve[fun[0, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
 P2spec = {P2[[1]], -P2[[2]] - h[P2[[1]]]};
 P3 = {1, y /. (Solve[fun[1, y] == 0, y])[[1]]};
 P3spec = {P3[[1]], -P3[[2]] - h[P3[[1]]]};
 ContourPlot[fun[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -15, 15}, 

  PlotPoints -> 50, 

  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.03], Red, Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P1], 
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P1spec], Blue, 
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P2], 
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P2spec], Orange, 
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P3], 
    Tooltip[#, #[[1]]] &@Point[P3spec]}], {k, -2, 7}]
```

I separated it out by empty lines just to make it visible in the code. 
It may improve the quality of the plot. Play with the number of points. 
The result should look as follows:

[image]

Have fun!